# What is the difference between the renders 'react-DOM' and 'react-DOM/client' import in react JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, react-dom, renderer

I'm curios to know why react provided the two import libraries

I have tried both the methods but I couldn't find any difference with both of them!

Answer (score 1):

**react-dom/client** provides just methods for client development.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-client.html

It can't be used for server side development.
For example well-known function **renderToString** for SSR is exported from **react-dom/server** but not from **react-dom/client**

**react-dom** contains both of them.

Answer (score 1):

The react-dom package provides both server and client.

1. react-dom/client (this helps to render the components on the client means browser)
2. react-dom/server (APIs let you render React components to HTML on the server

there are a few more entry points in react-dom that will be deprecated

- findDOMNode
- render
- hydrate
- unmountComponentAtNode

so they are divided.