# React error in index.js, "Uncaught ReferenceError: dom is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, react-dom

I'm building a React App,
I'm using Babel and Webpack as module bundler.

While writing the **index.js** the Application started sending me an error about the dom that is not defined,
but actually I've imported the "react-dom" library as the documentation has proposed to do.
Below I share the code, please help me.

*package.json*

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.22.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

const myFirstElement = <h1>Hello React!</h1>

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(myFirstElement);
```

I've tryed to install two times the library and installed the other one so called "react-router-dom".
I made a simpler index.js that doesn't render the <App/> from *App.js,* but It still does not work.

I'm expecting to see the projects running without problems.

Comment: A bit OT, but shouldn't it be `index.jsx` instead of `index.js` since you use JSX features inside?

Comment: @Geshode

This comment is useless.
The error message is wrote in the title, read better! 
'dom is not defined'

Comment: @Leonardo, what Geshode meant is we need more information regarding where the error is coming from in the files and whether or not there are any other related errors. Error messages do reveal a lot of helpful info. It is quite possible that we may be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @SuryasishPaul
That's the error that I've: https://ibb.co/89XPTtv (screenshot)

Comment: Hey, so your problem looks similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35284700/19119712 Do you mind sharing your index.html as well?

Comment: @SuryasishPaul I'm sorry but the problem is not the same.
My problem is React - related.
That's my index.js -> https://ctxt.io/2/AACQz_YXFw

Comment: Cool. I'll see if I can find anything else regarding the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this problem I've asked for help online, after many hours of researching the issue was found inside the bable file that was bad created.

Comment: Problem with transforming jsx?

Comment: @SuryasishPaul
No

Answer (score 1):

Your `ReactDom` import statement seems to be the issue. Instead of importing ReactDom from `"react-dom/client";` import it from `"react-dom";`. Please let me know if the change worked if/when you make the change.

Comment: After various test I can say that the problem is React and not webpack or babel.
If I don't use React the app works properly, so Now I must understand why React does not work

Comment: Hey, so you can try the change I mentioned in my revised answer above. Also you check out this QnA here as it might just be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74446354/19119712